# Unable to serve static files

Tags: rust, actix-web

Since the task is to distribute pictures - I follow the next guide:
https://actix.rs/docs/static-files/

For example, I created a directory (`static`) in the project and uploaded 1 image to it:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Then I write the following code:
(pay attention only to the lines (there are only two) with comments: `// Taken from the guide`)

```
use actix_cors::Cors;
use actix_web::{http, web, get, post, App, HttpResponse, HttpServer, Result};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use actix_files::Files;  // Taken from the guide

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct MyObj {
    name: String,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Clone)]
struct MyParams {
    foo: Option<String>,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct MyResponseObj {
    name: String,
    params: MyParams,
}

#[get("/{name}")]
async fn index_get(path: web::Path<MyObj>, params: web::Query<MyParams>) -> Result<HttpResponse> {

    Ok(HttpResponse::Ok().json(MyResponseObj {
        name: path.name.to_string(),
        params: params.clone(),
    }))
}

#[post("/{name}")]
async fn index_post(path: web::Path<MyObj>, params: web::Json<MyParams>) -> Result<HttpResponse> {

    hello().await;
    println!("{:?}", params.foo);
    println!("{:?}", path.name);

    Ok(HttpResponse::Ok().json(MyResponseObj {
        name: path.name.to_string(),
        params: params.clone(),
    }))
}


#[actix_rt::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {

    HttpServer::new(|| App::new()
        .wrap(
            Cors::new() // <- Construct CORS middleware builder
              .allowed_origin("http://localhost:3000")
              .allowed_methods(vec!["GET", "POST"])
              .allowed_headers(vec![http::header::AUTHORIZATION, http::header::ACCEPT])
              .allowed_header(http::header::CONTENT_TYPE)
              .max_age(3600)
              .finish())
        .service(Files::new("/static", ".")) // Taken from the guide
        .service(index_get)
        .service(index_post)

    )
        .bind("127.0.0.1:8088")?
        .run()
        .await
}
```

Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "hello_world"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Mike_Kharkov <yamaradg@gmail.com>"]
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
actix-web = "3.0.1"
actix-rt = "1.1.1"
actix-cors = "0.3.0"
actix-files = "0.3.0"
postgres = "0.17.5"
serde = { version = "1.0.116", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0"
json = "0.12"
tokio-postgres = "0.5.5"
tokio = "0.2.22"
env_logger = "0.7.1"
```

Question:
What else needs to be written (and where exactly) so that it becomes possible to refer to the above picture (for example, from localhost) and not get this kind of error?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: The error says that it is not a valid image, but what data did it actually send?

Comment: Data isn't necessary for this case.
I need what would image from my server open in the browser.
What do I need for it?

Comment: I understand what you want. What did the server send? I need to know so I can better understand the issue you are experiencing.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is solved:

```
.service(Files::new("/static", std::path::Path::new(env!("CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR")).join("static")))
```

[image]